# Abu Dhabi Airport: transit visa

Tags: transit-visas, uae, abu-dhabi

I am citizen of Uzbekistan and I do not have any type of UAE visa. I plan to fly Samarkand,Uzbekistan(SKD)-Abu Dhabi,UAE(AUH)-Tashkent,Uzbekistan(TAS) by Wizz Air Abu Dhabi. Transit time in Abu Dhabi (AUH) is more than 48 hours and less than 96 hours. I would like to apply for [Transit Visa Single Entry](https://www.etihad.com/en/fly-etihad/visas) which has duration of 4 days.

1. According to [the official portal of UAE government](https://u.ae/en/information-and-services/visiting-and-exploring-the-uae/transit-visa), "**Only the UAE based-airlines** you are travelling through can arrange your transit visa prior to your journey". But I could not find Wizz Air Abu Dhabi [here](https://u.ae/en/information-and-services/visiting-and-exploring-the-uae/how-to-get-to-the-uae/booking-air-tickets). Question: is Wizz Air Abu Dhabi UAE based airline and can I get transit visa if I fly with Wizz Air Abu Dhabi? If yes, how can I apply for transit visa: via the airline or other website?
2. Samarkand and Tashkent are cities in the same country. According to [the Etihad's website](https://www.etihad.com/en/fly-etihad/visas), "Transit Visa
   Single Entry: For passengers transiting through Abu Dhabi International Airport for a period of between eight hours and four calendar days and **travelling onward to a third destination**" and this does not contain information about country. Am I eligible for transit visa if I travel from/to the same country but different cities?

Comment: You can apply for transit visa through Etihad. No problem if you are not flying with them. This is very common. I have done it myself. I have no idea about the second part of the question. You will only get a visa if they consider it a transit.